# El Capitan UI smoothness on Intel Iris?

Tags: performance, macos, video-adapter

is there anyone who have already tried El Capitan GM on 2013 MBPr (Intel Iris, integrated video)? I'm experiencing freezes and UI smoothness issues with my MBPr 13 late 2013 on Yosemite, so now I'm really doubt about installing the El Capitan, which possibly will bring even more performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Mac Mini 2014 has an Intel Iris Pro graphics. Upgrading from Yosemite to El Capitan definitly improved the overall smoothness. Resizing Finder windows is buttery smooth, for example. Switching the preference panes is just as smooth as it was on Mavericks.
It's noticable in about all applications. El Capitan is definitly an improvement.

Comment: The most interesting things are switching between desktops, opening Mission Control.  How do you feel?

Comment: Mission Control runs at constant 60 fps, probably because the blurred wallpaper was removed. Anyway, never had a single fps drop since beta 1. Desktop switching works the same way.

Comment: Oh, I forgot one important thing. The screen resolution. I'm not sure if you run at 4K or something comparable with retina... So the performance issues is much more rare for you.

Comment: Just installed El Capitan. Wow. Spectacular smoothness in compare witn Yosemite!